# Disable text input without disabling text area

Tags: jquery, textarea, disabled-input

I have a text area. Once it has reached a certain character limit I want to disable the users ability to enter anymore text, but allow them to press backspace and/or delete some text.

I have tried:

```
.prop('disabled', true);
```

However, this does disable the users ability to add more text, it disables the text area, not allowing the user to delete some text, via the delete button, backspace etc.

Is this possible? If so, how do i do it?

Comment: Set the maxlength attribute of the  textarea

Comment: +1 to that @GruffBunny unless it was a "word limit"

Comment: This disables the text area and doesnt allow the user to press backspace etc

Comment: Just tried it in Chrome 34 and maxlength doesn't disable the text area. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/JHeDv/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As **Gruff Bunny** said, `maxlength` is the shortest and easiest way to go:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/H8Zbq/110/)**

However, Chrome does not support this regarding text, but for numbers by doing like so (example):

```
<input type="number" max="10" />
```

There is however a possible way to go around this issue regarding Chrome, further reading:

**http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/03-maxlength.html**